# IIS rewrite default rule for matching all documents

Tags: iis, rewrite, asp.net

I am trying to setup rewrite rules. I am using  web.config.

I have many multiple files -  .aspx and html files under same folder.

And I add one rule that rewrites abc.html to  abc.aspx  and this works fine.
But then calls to other files under same folder all return "Internal Server Error".
So should I be adding a "default" rule for other matching documents under same folder?]

```
    <rewrite>
    <rules>
    <rule name="abcrule" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^abc.html$" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="../abc.aspx" />
    </rule>
    </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Well no. Such rewrite config works fine for us. Are there no usable events in the server event log?

Comment: Learn what is regular expression and then revise your rule to match more files.